# SPRING /JPA - JPQL and Hibernate - repository - can I make a condition on child elements?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have @Entity of Customer who has collection of Coupons - (join table Customer_Coupons).

I want to create a JPQL query that returns Customer's Coupons only from certain type. it means that the condition is on the collection elements.

Is that possible?

Here is the Customer Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customers")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "cust_name")
private String custName;


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "customer_coupon", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"cust_id"), // this class
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id")
)

Collection<Coupon> coupons; 
private Set<Coupon> coupons = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Yest you can...

Comment: What is type of condition you want ? You can filter your collection, which related with customer object, but better to use some sql query with 'WHERE' sentence

Answer (score 0):

Specify JPQL NamedQuery "Customer.findAllWithCouponType"

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Customer.findAllWithCouponType",
                query = "SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.coupons cp WHERE cp.type = :type"
        )
)
@Table(name = "Customers")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "cust_name")
    private String custName;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_coupon", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =
            "cust_id"), // this class
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id")
    )
    private List<Coupon> coupons;
}
```

Then in repository class create NamedQuery ("Customer.findAllWithCouponType"), and set parameter ("type")

```
@Service("customerRepository")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CastomerRepository implements IRepository<Customer> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Customer> findAllWithCouponType(String type) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAllWithCouponType", Customer.class)
            .setParameter("type", type).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try that.